# What is the Python equivalent of `set -x` in shell?

Tags: python, shell, debugging

Please suggest Python command which is equivalent of `set -x` in shell scripts.

Is there a way to print/log each source file line executed by Python?

Comment: I was searching for an "equivalent of `bash -x`".

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the [trace](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/trace.html) module:

```
python -m trace -t your_script.py
```

The command line above will display every line of code as it is executed.

Comment: Good answer, but this will give a ton of output.  I'd do something like `python -m trace -t your_script.py | grep your_script.py`, or whatever file it calls from which you care about the execution trace.

Comment: One thing it doesn't seem to do that I like in bash -x is seeing what variables resolve to as the lines are being run. Is there a switch for that?

Answer (score 22):

to get a proper equivalent of `bash -x` using the `trace` module, one needs to use `--ignore-dir` to block the printing of source lines of every module imported, e.g. `python -m trace --trace --ignore-dir /usr/lib/python2.7 --ignore-dir /usr/lib/pymodules repost.py`, adding more `--ignore-dir` directives as necessary for other module locations.

this becomes important when attempting to locate slow-loading modules such as `requests` which spit out millions of source lines for several minutes on a slow machine. the proper use of `--ignore-dir` cuts the time down to a few seconds, and shows only the lines from your own code.

```
$ time python -m trace --trace repost.py 2>&1 | wc
3710176 16165000 200743489

real    1m54.302s
user    2m14.360s
sys 0m1.344s
```

vs.

```
$ time python -m trace --trace --ignore-dir /usr/lib/python2.7 --ignore-dir /usr/lib/pymodules repost.py 2>&1 | wc
     42     210    2169

real    0m12.570s
user    0m12.421s
sys 0m0.108s
```

this doesn't really answer your question; you asked for a Python equivalent of `set -x`. a simple way to approximate that is with `sys.settrace()`:

```
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python -OO
'''
test program for sys.settrace
'''
import sys, linecache
TRACING = []

def traceit(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "line":
        lineno = frame.f_lineno
        line = linecache.getline(sys.argv[0], lineno)
        if TRACING:
            print "%d: %s" % (lineno, line.rstrip())
    return traceit

def test():
    print 'this first line should not trace'
    TRACING.append(True)
    print 'this line and the following ought to show'
    print "that's all folks"
    TRACING.pop()
    print 'this last line should not trace'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.settrace(traceit)
    test()
```

which, when run, gives:

```
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ ./test.py
this first line should not trace
19:     print 'this line and the following ought to show'
this line and the following ought to show
20:     print "that's all folks"
that's all folks
21:     TRACING.pop()
this last line should not trace
```

eliminating the line 'TRACING.pop()' from the trace output is left as an exercise for the reader.

sources: https://pymotw.com/2/sys/tracing.html and http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html

Comment: I write a small alias that excludes all stdlib by default: alias pyx="python -m trace --ignore-dir $(python -c 'import os, sys; print(os.pathsep.join([p for p in sys.path if "python3.5" in p or "python2.7" in p]))') -t"

Comment: This one is shorter and handles virtualenv without the need of re-source: alias pyx="python -m trace --ignore-dir \$(python -c 'import os, sys; print(os.pathsep.join(sys.path[1:]))') -t"

Comment: It would be nice if you updated your answer to also work with Python 3

Comment: @tjanez in case Python 3 functionality is still interesting to you, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I liked @jcomeau_ictx's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33449763/2454357) very much, but it has a small flaw, which is why I extended on it a bit. The problem is that jcomeau_ictx's 'traceit' function only works correctly if all code to be traced is within the file that is called with `python file.py` (let's call it the host file). If you call any imported functions, you get a lot of line numbers without code. The reason for this is that `line = linecache.getline(sys.argv[0], lineno)` always tries to get the line of code from the host file (`sys.argv[0]`). This can easily be corrected, as the name of the file that actually contains the traced line of code can be found in `frame.f_code.co_filename`. This now may produce a lot of output, which is why one probably would want to have a bit more control.

There is also another bit to notice. According to the `sys.settrace()` documentation:

> The trace function is invoked (with event set to 'call') whenever a
>   new local scope is entered

In other words, the code to be traced has to be inside a function.

To keep everything tidy, I decided to put everything into an own file called `setx.py`. The code should be pretty self-explanatory. There is, however, one piece of code that is needed for Python 3 compatibility, which deals with the differences between Python 2 and 3 with respect to how modules are imported. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40945851/2454357). The code should now also work both with Python 2 and 3.

```
##setx.py
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, linecache

##adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33449763/2454357
##emulates bash's set -x and set +x

##for turning tracing on and off
TRACING = False

##FILENAMES defines which files should be traced
##by default this will on only be the host file 
FILENAMES = [sys.argv[0]]

##flag to ignore FILENAMES and alwas trace all files
##off by default
FOLLOWALL = False

def traceit(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "line":
        ##from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40945851/2454357
        while frame.f_code.co_filename.startswith('<frozen'):
            frame = frame.f_back
        filename = frame.f_code.co_filename
##        print(filename, FILENAMES)
        if TRACING and (
            filename in FILENAMES or
            filename+'c' in FILENAMES or
            FOLLOWALL
        ):
            lineno = frame.f_lineno
            line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno)
            print("{}, {}: {}".format(filename, lineno, line.rstrip()))
    return traceit

sys.settrace(traceit)
```

I then test the functionality with this code:

```
##setx_tester.py
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import setx
from collections import OrderedDict

import file1
from file1 import func1
import file2
from file2 import func2

def inner_func():
    return 15

def test_func():

    x=5
    print('the value of x is', x)

    ##testing function calling:
    print('-'*50)
    ##no further settings
    print(inner_func())
    print(func1())
    print(func2())

    print('-'*50)
    ##adding the file1.py to the filenames to be traced
    ##it appears that the full path to the file is needed:
    setx.FILENAMES.append(file1.__file__)
    print(inner_func())
    print(func1())
    print(func2())

    print('-'*50)
    ##restoring original:
    setx.FILENAMES.pop()

    ##setting that all files should be traced:
    setx.FOLLOWALL = True
    print(inner_func())
    print(func1())
    print(func2())

##turn tracing on:
setx.TRACING = True
outer_test = 42  ##<-- this line will not show up in the output
test_func()
```

The files `file1.py` and `file2.py` look like this:

```
##file1.py
def func1():
    return 7**2
```

and

```
##file2.py
def func2():
    return 'abc'*3
```

The output then looks like this:

```
setx_tester.py, 16:     x=5
setx_tester.py, 17:     print('the value of x is', x)
the value of x is 5
setx_tester.py, 20:     print('-'*50)
--------------------------------------------------
setx_tester.py, 22:     print(inner_func())
setx_tester.py, 12:     return 15
15
setx_tester.py, 23:     print(func1())
49
setx_tester.py, 24:     print(func2())
abcabcabc
setx_tester.py, 26:     print('-'*50)
--------------------------------------------------
setx_tester.py, 29:     setx.FILENAMES.append(file1.__file__)
setx_tester.py, 30:     print(inner_func())
setx_tester.py, 12:     return 15
15
setx_tester.py, 31:     print(func1())
**path to file**/file1.py, 2:     return 7**2
49
setx_tester.py, 32:     print(func2())
abcabcabc
setx_tester.py, 34:     print('-'*50)
--------------------------------------------------
setx_tester.py, 36:     setx.FILENAMES.pop()
setx_tester.py, 39:     setx.FOLLOWALL = True
setx_tester.py, 40:     print(inner_func())
setx_tester.py, 12:     return 15
15
setx_tester.py, 41:     print(func1())
**path to file**/file1.py, 2:     return 7**2
49
setx_tester.py, 42:     print(func2())
**path to file**/file2.py, 2:     return 'abc'*3
abcabcabc
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also [viztracer](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/viztracer) which is like `trace` but much more complete and with a GUI.

You can use it like this:

```
$ pip install viztracer --user
$ viztracer --log_func_args --log_func_retval source.py
```

It generates a report that can be visualized like so `vizviewer report.json`