# inspect who imported me

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, introspection

There are two files:

```
# the_imported.py
import inspect
imported_by_fname = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_filename
print('{} was imported by {}'.format(__name__, imported_by_fname))
```

And:

```
# the_importer.py
import the_imported
```

When executed with Python 2.7:

```
$ python the_importer.py 
the_imported was imported by the_importer.py
```

When executed with Python 3.5:

```
$ python3 the_importer.py 
the_imported was imported by <frozen importlib._bootstrap>
```

What is that weird thing `<frozen importlib._bootstrap>` all about?  What happened with `import` and/or `inspect` that changed this behaviour?   How can we get that Python 2 filename introspection working again on Python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.1 and newer the [import machinery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) is implemented in Python, which makes it possible to access its call stack. To illustrate this, I'll put the following code

```
from traceback import print_stack
print_stack()
```

to *the_imported.py* and import it.

On Python 2 that code prints

```
  File "the_importer.py", line 2, in <module>
    import the_imported
  File ".../the_imported.py", line 3, in <module>
    print_stack()
```

But on Python 3 the output is much more verbose:

```
  File "the_importer.py", line 2, in <module>
    import the_imported
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 677, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".../the_imported.py", line 2, in <module>
    print_stack()
```

Before Python 3.3, these lines [were also included in tracebacks](http://bugs.python.org/issue15110).

To achieve the desired result you could walk up the call stack to find the first frame, the file name of which doesn't start with `<frozen importlib`.

```
from traceback import extract_stack

for x in extract_stack():
    if not x[0].startswith('<frozen importlib'):
        print('{} was imported by {}'.format(__name__, x[0]))
        break
```

Answer (score 6):

There's just more on the stack in Python 3.  `importlib` is now responsible for importing:

```
# the_imported.py
from inspect import getframeinfo, getouterframes, currentframe
frame = currentframe()
while frame:
    print(frame.f_code.co_filename)
    frame = frame.f_back
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\the_imported.py
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>
C:\Users\user\Desktop\the_importer.py
```

You could do something like:

```
# the_imported.py
from inspect import getframeinfo, getouterframes, currentframe
frame = currentframe().f_back
while frame.f_code.co_filename.startswith('<frozen'):
    frame = frame.f_back
print(frame.f_code.co_filename)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\the_importer.py
```