# Redhat python trace

Tags: python, debugging, redhat, trace

To enable python debug according to [What is the Python equivalent of `set -x` in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760381/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-set-x-in-shell) I need to run `python -m trace --trace repost.py ...`
In redhat our pipelines starts script as

```
scl enable rh-python36 "./cli.py param1 param2 ..."
```

I have tried

```
scl enable rh-python36 "-m trace --trace  ./cli.py param1 param2 ..."  
scl enable rh-python36 -m trace --trace  "./cli.py param1 param2 ..."
```

none worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot test it, but I would try: `scl enable rh-python36 "python3.6 -m trace --trace  ./cli.py param1 param2 ..."`

Comment: @VPfB you right it worked, but it logs a lot.